# List.Add() not working

Tags: apex, trigger, list

I've got the following code snippet in a trigger handler class

```
x1 = trigger.new;
List<Id> listx = new List(Id);

    For(integer i = 0; i < x1.size(); i++ ) {

         System.debug('Loop run:'+ i);    

                listx.add(x1[i].Ben_Loan__r.id);

          }

System.debug('listx:' + listx );
```

In the debug logs, 'listx' is shown as null even though it should work. Ben_Loan__r.id is the id of a look up field.

When I try a different For Loop as below, I still get an error "Variable id does not exist".

```
   For(List <Beneficiary_Loan_Repayment__c> LX1 : x1){
            listx.add(LX1.Beneficiary_Loan__r.id);
}
```

Any idea what the issue could be? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You cannot access related fields in `trigger context`, only fields on the object that is in transaction can be accessed. If you want to access related fields, you will have to query it explicitly. If you try to access relationship fields in trigger context, it will return `null`, hence your list is showing null.

In your case, as you are accessing the `ID` field, you can access directly using the `lookup field` instead of using relationship field.

You can replace this below code

```
listx.add(x1[i].Ben_Loan__r.id);
```

with

```
listx.add(x1[i].Ben_Loan__c);
```

Similarly, you can replace below code if its a lookup field

```
listx.add(LX1.Beneficiary_Loan__r.id);
```

with

```
listx.add(LX1.Beneficiary_Loan__c);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked (listx.add(x1[i].Ben_Loan__c))  but listx.add(LX1.Beneficiary_Loan__c); didn't work

Comment: I don't think `Beneficiary_Loan__c` is a lookup field, if it would have been a lookup field, then the compiler wouldn't have given the error `Variable id does not exist`. You can traverse through to the parent only via lookup/master detail fields.